# ActiveRecord joins query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Attempting to utilize ActiveRecord's `joins` interface with the following:

```
Foo.joins(:user).where(user_id: users).where('users.some_col IS NOT NULL')
```

In this particular case, `Foo` has a `belongs_to :user` and `User` has the relation `has_many :foos`

In this particular case, I'm getting the following error:

`Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous`

`users` in this case is an array of user ids.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Can you show the generated query?. i.e. using `to_sql`

Answer (score 1):

Because column `id` exists in both tables `foos` and `users`, so the DB doesn't know which one you're referring to in the where statement, try :

`where(foos: {id: something})`

or

`where(users: {id: something})`

Comment: Can you elaborate? Is the issue with my first where clause or second?

Comment: @randombits can you edit your question with the exact sql query? then I can help better.